# create a running (moving) average with a continuously updating length from fixed date in time to create a distribution mean

Tags: pine-script, trading, algorithmic-trading, moving-average, tradingview-api

I want to take a stock chart and create an indicator that will display the MEAN/average of ROC(rate of change) of daily closing prices, as a continuously updating length moving average (a running average) starting from a FIXED date. For example, the rate of change in the s&p500 between january 4th/5th 2022 was -1.94%, and between jan 5th/6th was -.10%.  Therefore, this indicator would calculate (from fixed date january 4th), a 2 period moving average using [-1.94% and -.10% = 1.02%]. THEN on january 7th, the indicator will calculate a 3 period moving average of the 3 daily roc's starting from jan 4th. NExt, on january 8th,  it will calculate a 4 period moving average of 4 roc's from jan 4th etc.......I started a code but I cannot get it to work properly. This indicator would be useful to find the MEAN in a trend as it evolves every day, (a probability distribution) without having to change the moving average length each day (which you could do, but adds more time).

```
//@version=4
study("velocity", shorttitle="vel", overlay=true)

timeYear = input(2022, title="Year", minval=1991, maxval=2100, type=input.integer)
timeMonth = input(1, title="Month", minval=1, maxval=12, type=input.integer)
timeDay = input(04, title="Day", minval=1, maxval=31, type=input.integer)
timeHours = input(9, title="Hours", minval=0, maxval=23, type=input.integer)
timeMinutes = input(30, title="Minutes", minval=0, maxval=59, type=input.integer)
timeSeconds = input(0, title="Seconds", minval=0, maxval=59, type=input.integer)
// Initilization of variables only once
var delta = 0 

// start time at 0 from a particular time interval
if(year == timeYear and month == timeMonth and dayofmonth == timeDay and hour == timeHours and minute == timeMinutes and second == timeSeconds)
    delta := 0
    

// Count number of bars
if(year >= timeYear and month >= timeMonth and dayofmonth > timeDay)
    delta += 1    
plotchar(delta, title="days passed from startdate", color=color.green, char='')
// set to TOP so it doesnt mess up chart scale
delta0 = delta-delta

// rate of change and moving average of ROC
length = input(1, minval=1)
source = input(close, "Source")
roc = (source[delta]-source[delta][1]) / source[delta]
rocma = sma(roc, delta)
plot(rocma)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One limit with Pine script is that there is a limit too how many bars back you can reference. In order to overcome that limit, I would use an `array` to which I will add up to 100,000 elements, and than calculate the average of those elements:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

var roc_array = array.new_float(0)
float avg_roc_array = array.avg(roc_array)

start = input.time(timestamp("04 Oct 2022 00:00:00"), "Start date")

if time >= start
    roc = ((close / close[1]) - 1) * 100
    array.push(roc_array, roc)
    avg_roc_array := array.avg(roc_array)

plot(avg_roc_array)
```

Or you can use the same logic with the code you have already written. Just keep in mind that you need to check that the value of `delta` is above `0` before making any calculation, and than just create a series of `roc` and calculate the `sma` of that series:

```
//@version=4
study("velocity", shorttitle="vel", overlay=true)

timeYear = input(2022, title="Year", minval=1991, maxval=2100, type=input.integer)
timeMonth = input(1, title="Month", minval=1, maxval=12, type=input.integer)
timeDay = input(04, title="Day", minval=1, maxval=31, type=input.integer)
timeHours = input(9, title="Hours", minval=0, maxval=23, type=input.integer)
timeMinutes = input(30, title="Minutes", minval=0, maxval=59, type=input.integer)
timeSeconds = input(0, title="Seconds", minval=0, maxval=59, type=input.integer)
// Initilization of variables only once
var delta = 0 

// start time at 0 from a particular time interval
if(year == timeYear and month == timeMonth and dayofmonth == timeDay and hour == timeHours and minute == timeMinutes and second == timeSeconds)
    delta := 0

// Count number of bars
if(year >= timeYear and month >= timeMonth and dayofmonth > timeDay)
    delta += 1    
plotchar(delta, title="days passed from startdate", color=color.green, char='')

// rate of change and moving average of ROC
source = input(close, "Source")
float rocma = na
float roc = 0

if delta >= 1
    roc := ((source - source[1]) / source[1]) * 100
    rocma := sma(roc, delta)

plot(rocma)
```

**EDIT:**

After thinking about it, I thought of a much simpler way to achieve the same goal:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

start = input.time(timestamp("04 Oct 2022 00:00:00"), "Start date")

roc = time >= start ? ((close / close[1]) - 1) * 100 : na
bars_since_first_roc = ta.barssince(na(roc))
total_roc = bars_since_first_roc > 0 ? math.sum(roc, bars_since_first_roc) : na
avg_roc = total_roc / bars_since_first_roc

plot(avg_roc)
```

Comment: hi there! thanks very much for your answer. this seems to work well but I have encounted a slight problem. I am using the second version of your answer (starting with timeyear = input). The readout that counts the number of days that have passed sticks and read the same day every so often, and over a long series of days will undercount to total. I am not sure why?

Comment: Your `if` statement requires the day of the bar to be more than the day you've asked for. That's why if you set the date you want to start for October 4th, then November 3rd won't meet the criteria you've determined (because 3 is not bigger than 4, even thought it's on a later month). It's best if you use timestamps instead